# Saving check boxes choices with Perl and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, perl, postgresql

I'm trying to create a user's preference page that has a bunch of check boxes letting the user decide how they want to receive their notifications. Here is my current HTML form for preferences:

```
<form method="post">
  <table id="preferences" class = "preferences">
    <tr class="headers">
      <th class = "preferences">Preference</th>
      <th class = "preferences">Value</th>
      <th class = "preferences">Notification Preferences</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class = "preferences">Default Post Markup</td>
      <td class = "preferences">
        <select name="default_markup">
          <% foreach(USystem::Markup->markup_types) {
                 print Usystem::Utils::option_tag($_->{id}, $_->{name}, $prefs->value(1));
             } %>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "notification-option" id = "all-post"> All Posts <br/>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "notification-option" id = "others-post"> Other's Posts <br/>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "notification-option" id = "client-post"> Cilent's Post <br/>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "notification-option" id = "assign-post"> Task Assigned
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" class="submitrow"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Preferences" /></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I just added the 4 checkboxes and I need help saving them into the database where I use a boolean to determine if they are checked or not.

My Perl script on the HTML page that runs when the "Save Preferences" button is selected:

```
my $form = $Request->Params;
my $prefs = USystem::UserPrefs->new($user->userid);

if($Request->{Method} =~ /POST/i) {
    my $dbh = USystem::DB->new;

    if($form->{submit} eq "Save Preferences") {
        $prefs->value($USER_PREF_MARKUPTYPE, $form->{default_markup});
        $prefs->update;
    }
    $Response->Redirect('/preferences');
}
```

the $Request->Params is basically the same as CGI->Params()

this is UserPrefs:

```
package USystems::UserPrefs;

use strict;
use USystems::DB;

sub new {
    my $self = shift;
    my $class = ref($self) || $self;
    my $userid = shift;

    $self = bless {}, $class;
    $self->{dbh} = USystems::DB->new;

    if($userid) {
        $self->userid($userid);
        $self->__populate;
    }

    return $self;
}

sub __populate {
    my $self = shift;

    my $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("select prefid, value from user_preferences where userid=?");
    $sth->execute($self->userid);
    while(my $href = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
        $self->value($href->{PREFID}, $href->{VALUE});
    }
    $sth->finish();
}

sub update {
    my $self = shift;

    my $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("delete from user_preferences where userid=?");
    $sth->execute($self->userid);
    $sth->finish;

    $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("insert into user_preferences(userid, prefid, value) values(?, ?, ?)");
    while(my ($prefid, $value) = each %{$self->{PREFS}}) {
        $sth->execute($self->userid, $prefid, $value);
    }
    $sth->finish;
}

sub userid {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{USERID} = shift if(@_);
    $self->{USERID};
}

sub value {
    my $self = shift;
    my $prefid = shift;
    $self->{PREFS}->{$prefid} = shift if(@_);
    return $self->{PREFS}->{$prefid};
}

1
```

How would I go about storing the values of whether the check boxes are checked or not as well as update my current Perl script to take in the values. I'm pretty new to Perl haven't had much luck. I'd be great if you can give an explanation to why you did what you did too.

Please let me know if there's more information you need. Thanks

Comment: You don't show how the `$self->{PREFS}` hash is defined (perhaps in `USystem::UserPrefs->new`?), but it looks like all you need to do is make sure the additional fields go into there before you call `$prefs->update`

Comment: Is this the real code? The line `my $dbh = USystem::DB->new` create a new database handle which is unused throughout the block, after which it is thrown away

Comment: I added the UserPrefs->new and yeah,y $dbh = USystem::DB->new, is real code

Comment: Someone else code that part though am I'm just updating it with the new feature

Comment: I'm a really visual learner, can you show me a quick example

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really. You don't show how the data gets into `$self->{PREFS}` so I can't tell you how to add some more! Perhaps if you showed `USystem::UserPrefs->new`? Does the code as it is save the other preferences correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new with Perl and I'm modifying an existing system thats already implemented. I added `USystem::UserPrefs->new`but I'm not sure if thats what you are looking for. I'll see what other snippets of code seem relevant and add them as well

Comment: I've added the whole UserPrefs.pm

Comment: Okay I think you just need to add more calls to `$prefs->value` before you do the update. Read my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
my $prefs = USystem::UserPrefs->new($user->userid)
```

creates a new object and copies the current preferences for that user from the database. Afterwards you can acccess or update individual preferences using `$prefs->value(value_name [, new_value)`, and a call to `$prefs->update` will copy the current values back to the database

You already have

```
$prefs->value($USER_PREF_MARKUPTYPE, $form->{default_markup})
```

and you need to add more calls like that to set the values for other preferences before you call

```
$prefs->update
```

to save them all

Comment: Your answers great and explains things well. One question I have is how does the Perl script actually communicate with the checkboxes to access whether or not it is checked? Can you possibly give a example of how `$prefs->value(value_name [, new_value)` would be like with a checkbox being checked?

Comment: Your call `$form->{default_markup}` is one example of fetching data from the form. Your checkbox names are all `notification-option` which you may need to change, but try `$form->{notification-option}` to see what you get

Comment: Would I need to edit the UserPref->update code as well? Since im taking in more stuff

Comment: No, it just copies everything that's in the hash

Comment: I changed the name of Other'sPosts to `"others_post"` and then I added `$form->{others_post}` to `$prefs->value($USER_PREF_MARKUPTYPE, $form->{default_markup})` so I have `$prefs->value($USER_PREF_MARKUPTYPE, $form->{default_markup}, $form->{others_post})` but it didn't save the selection or update it in the table or anything. When I manually set the table to "true" in the database, it returns it to false after I hit the "Save Preferences" button